# HTTP Error 404: Not Found in downloading Caltech101 dataset

Tags: linux, download, dataset, google-colaboratory, tar

I am trying to download [Caltech101 dataset](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/Image_Datasets/Caltech101/) in Google colab, however I am getting the following error:

```
!wget 'http://www.vision.caltech.edu/Image_Datasets/Caltech256/256_ObjectCategories.tar.gz'
```

> '--2020-07-24 04:02:05--  http://www.vision.caltech.edu/Image_Datasets/Caltech256/256_ObjectCategories.tar.gz
> Resolving [www.vision.caltech.edu](http://www.vision.caltech.edu) ([www.vision.caltech.edu](http://www.vision.caltech.edu))... 34.208.54.77
> Connecting to [www.vision.caltech.edu](http://www.vision.caltech.edu) ([www.vision.caltech.edu](http://www.vision.caltech.edu))|34.208.54.77|:80... connected.
> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
> 2020-07-24 04:02:05 ERROR 404: Not Found.'

I also tried:

```
import urllib
urllib.request.urlretrieve(
    "http://www.vision.caltech.edu/Image_Datasets/Caltech101/101_ObjectCategories.tar.gz", "my-tar.gz"
)
```

and got the same error:

> HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 1 import urllib
> 2 urllib.request.urlretrieve(
> ----> 3     "http://www.vision.caltech.edu/Image_Datasets/Caltech101/101_ObjectCategories.tar.gz",
> "my-tar.gz"
> 4 )
>
> 6 frames /usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in urlretrieve(url,
> filename, reporthook, data)
> 246     url_type, path = splittype(url)
> 247
> --> 248     with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
> 249         headers = fp.info()
> 250
>
> /usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout,
> cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
> 221     else:
> 222         opener = _opener
> --> 223     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
> 224
> 225 def install_opener(opener):
>
> /usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in open(self, fullurl, data,
> timeout)
> 530         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
> 531             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
> --> 532             response = meth(req, response)
> 533
> 534         return response
>
> /usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in http_response(self, request,
> response)
> 640         if not (200 <= code < 300):
> 641             response = self.parent.error(
> --> 642                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
> 643
> 644         return response
>
> /usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
> 568         if http_err:
> 569             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
> --> 570             return self._call_chain(*args)
> 571
> 572 # XXX probably also want an abstract factory that knows when it makes
>
> /usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind,
> meth_name, *args)
> 502         for handler in handlers:
> 503             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
> --> 504             result = func(*args)
> 505             if result is not None:
> 506                 return result
>
> /usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in http_error_default(self, req,
> fp, code, msg, hdrs)
> 648 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
> 649     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
> --> 650         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
> 651
> 652 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):
>
> HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Can you help me figure out what is the problem here?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in that the server doesn't actually have the content you are looking for.
The CalTech 256 dataset is not available on the site.

You can try downloading it from https://www.kaggle.com/jessicali9530/caltech256